# Removing items from a vector

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I'm looking for the most efficient way to remove multiple items from a vector?

Basically I will be searching for a flag within the vector and removing and objects that have that flag.

However, I have heard that erasing an object from a vector will mess up your iterators, so what is the most efficient way to loop though a vector (containing potentially thousands of objects) and remove those with a specific flag?

I am hoping to not have to loop through the vector multiple times.

Comment: `std::remove_if`.

Comment: Howto not mess the iterator up: `iterator = vector.erase(iterator);`

Comment: Does the ordering of the items in the vector matter?  If not, whenever you come across an item in the vector that you want to remove, set that item equal to the last item in the vector, and then call pop_back() on the vector.  By doing it that way you can remove any number of items from the vector in only O(N) time.  (Note that it does change the ordering of the items though, so if that's a problem, use std::remove_if() instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are multiple elements match the flag you should use `std::remove_if()`:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), v.end(), [](T const& e){ return e.flag(); }),
          v.end());
```

Using this approach moves each vector element at most once. Removing individual elements may move each element `O(n)` times.

Comment: I'm not sure if "up to O(n)" is a sensible expression. O(n) already means "Up to"...

Comment: Cheers, that's perfect :)

Comment: How could it move each element once, but also `O(n)` times?

Comment: @soandos: for example, assume you remove the first `n/2` elements from a sequence, one element at a time. You'll move each of the second half elements `n/2` times.

Comment: So what does "Using this approach moves each vector element at most once" mean? Did you mean remove?

Comment: @soandos: That the use of `std::remove_if()` combined with the two argument version of `vec.erase(it, end)` does **not** move each element more than once, while repeated use of `vec.erase(it)` can do.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm can sometimes be coupled elegantly with other utilities. For example, if your class looks like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    bool flag;               // either this...
    bool get_flag() const;   // ... or this
    // ...
};
```

Then you can use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to generate an accessor functor that returns the value of the member or invokes the member function, respectively:

```
std::mem_fn(&Foo::flag)
std::mem_fn(&Foo::get_flag)
```

Finally, you can use argument-dependent lookup to rely on namespace `std` to be found as soon as one of the argument types is from that namespace. For example:

```
#include <algorithm>   // for remove_if
#include <functional>  // for mem_fn
#include <iterator>    // for begin, end
#include <vector>      // for vector

std::vector<Foo> v = /* something */ ;

v.erase(remove_if(begin(v), end(v), std::mem_fn(&Foo::flag)), end(v));
```

Comment: See also [this code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37917) for some limitations of the `mem_fn` predicate.